# Crontab- run nosetests from a specific path

Tags: python, cron, nose

Hello I am trying to CD into a specific path and run my nosetests through crontab. 
I have tried a bunch of stuff and none of it has worked yet:

```
MAILTO = mail@yahoo.com
* * * * * . /Users/pamili/resources/tests ; nosetests

MAILTO = mail@yahoo.com
Path = /Users/pamili/resources/test
* * * * * Path/nosetests

MAILTO = mail@yahoo.com
Path = /Users/pamili/resources/test
* * * * * Path =. nosetests
```

None of it seems to work. Any suggestions are really helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: 
MAILTO = mail@yahoo.com

```
* * * * * cd /Users/pamili/resources/test && /dir/of/nosetests
```